# I am trying to Pipe the contents of a variable (array) to Get-ADUser

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Here is my code:

The contents of $EuropeUsers2 is: 
jsmith1
jsmith2
jsmith3
jsmith4

```
$EU = ForEach ($User in $EuropeUsers2) { Get-Aduser $User -Server "emea.abc.local" }
```

The error I am getting is something like: Get-ADUser : Cannot bind parameter 'Identity'. Cannot convert value "@{SamAccountName=jsmith1}"

I know I must be missing something small can someone please advise.

Comment: Works for me.  Are you sure that $EuropeUsers2 is a simple array?  What does `$EuropeUsers2.GetType()` return?

Comment: I poplulated $EuropeUsers2 by running `[string[]]$EuropeUsers2 = "user1", "user2", "user3"` and then ran your command and it worked.

Comment: There was a user Pero who commented $User.SamAccountName and that worked beautifully resolving my issue. Then he deleted his comment so I am unable to give him credit :(

Comment: Since that worked it means that the array contained Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADAccount objects, not strings.

Comment: SamAccountNames to be specific. Sorry if I mislead you it wasn't until your comment that I realized I should have mentioned the data TYPE contained in the Array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line of code resolves the issue

```
$EU = ForEach ($User in $EuropeUsers2) { Get-Aduser $User.SamAccountName -Server "emea.abc.local" }
```

Thank you Pero!